# Как не дать элементу установленному на картинки выйти за его рамки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Создать HTML-страницу с футбольным полем, которое занимает всю ширину и высоту экрана, и мячом размером **100px** на **100px**. Сделать так, чтобы при щелчке мышкой по полю, мяч плавно перемещался на место щелчка.

Учтите: необходимо, чтобы центр мяча останавливался именно там, где был совершен щелчок мышкой. Также предусмотрите, чтобы мяч не выходил за границы поля.

```js
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
  mydiv.style.left = (e.pageX - mydiv.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
  mydiv.style.top = (e.pageY - mydiv.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
}
```

```html
<div id=mypole style="background: no-repeat" "background-size: 100px">
  <img src="http://evergreen.org.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/kak-gazon-delayut-polosatum.jpg" />
</div>
<div id=mydiv style="position: absolute">
  <img src="http://yoway.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/street_black.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Любопытно понять,  почему у тебя мяч не в поле?

Comment: Просите я только начал учить потому приму любые советы по этому поводу что бы понять в чем проблема моего кода

Comment: Для начала: там неверный синтаксис HTML-разметки. Нужно исправить запись тэга с id = mypole. `style="background: no-repeat; background-size: 100px"` С точки зрения чистоты кода, конечно, CSS-стили стоит вынести в одельный файл.

Answer (score 2):

За плавность элемента отвечает правило  `css transition`.

Еще в примере автора не хватает кавычек в `ID`

Есть

> id=mypole

А должно быть

> id="mypole"

```js
const lea = document.querySelector("#lea");
const ball = document.querySelector("#ball");


ball.style.left = 0 + "px";
ball.style.top = 0 + "px";

lea.onclick = function(e) {
  ball.style.left = e.pageX - ball.offsetWidth / 2 + "px";
  ball.style.top = e.pageY - ball.offsetHeight / 2 + "px";

  if (lea.offsetHeight - 25 < e.pageY) {
    ball.style.top = lea.offsetHeight - 25 + "px";
  }

  if (lea.offsetWidth - 25 < e.pageX) {
    ball.style.left = lea.offsetWidth - 25 + "px";
  }

  if (e.pageY < ball.offsetHeight / 2) {
    ball.style.top = 0 + "px";
  }
  if (e.pageX < ball.offsetWidth / 2) {
    ball.style.left = 0 + "px";
  }
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#lea {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

#ball {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="lea">
  <div id="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: _> В примере автора не хватает кавычек._ Кавычки при записи значений аттрибутов не обязательны. Вам бы ещё добавить для поля свойство `overflow:hidden`, чтобы не было прокрутки.

Comment: а каким образом  ограничить  выход кружка за рамки  картинки?

Comment: @mymedia, путь учиться писать по стандарту...

Comment: @Darkkiss, минутку... Забыл про это

Comment: border-radius: 50%; - Устанавливает радиус скругления уголков рамки. но  рамку оно не округлило,  как именно это работает?

Comment: @Darkkiss, в смысле не округлило?

Comment: я может просто не понимаю сути работы этого свойства но   думал border-radius: 50% округлит background , ,белый фон вокруг мяча

Comment: а что бы элемент не отображался  за полем  необходимо  прописать  условие в javascript если позиция мяча больше  координат поля  то элемент  мяча "hide"? но как задать  координаты для проверки если  поле это картинка... а не нарисованное  вручную

Comment: @Darkkiss, я собирался дополнить ответ, но отвлекли... Смогу только позже дополнить ответ... Но я несколько не понял вопроса в комментарии, надо чтобы мяч не отображался, если он за полем или не выходил на пределы поля...

Comment: вообще не выходил за пределы поля, я просто рассуждаю как  это сделать. Думал что  надо его спрятать, но судя по  тому что вы написали я не прав и можно просто ограничить движение элемента- мяча (элементом -поле)

Comment: Ты верно понял... Определяешь положение клика и край площадки ....

Comment: @Air  if(e.PageX>lea.Width && e.PageY>lea.Height)  //  если  клик мышки больше  ширины поля или высоты 
          ball.style.left=lea.Width-(e.pageX - ball.offsetWidth / 2)  // присвоить координаты мячу ширину поля отнять половину ширины мяча что бы весь мяч уперся в край поля. И тоже самое для  высоты...

 так?

Comment: не сработало...

Comment: Глянь пример.... Так?